# AppleScript to Javascript for Adobe

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript I use in Adobe Acrtobat. The script basically makes sure when you click on a bookmark, it goes to the correct page, but also fills the page. So if the bookmark links to the middle of the page, you start at the top of the screen with the heading in the middle.

I want a way to do this on a windows computer, but I can't figure out how to do this? Any advise or help would be appreciated.

This is the AppleScript

```
tell application "Adobe Acrobat Pro"
  tell active doc
    tell bookmarks
      set fit type to fit page
    end tell
  end tell
end tell
```

Comment: You are basically asking for an AppleScript alternative for Windows. Maybe some of these could help if the action you are looking for is on the menu. Or alternatively, in Default layout and zoom, select Single Page (or else) in the Page Layout drop-down option and select Fit page in the Zoom drop-down option.